Using MS GraphAPI how to get the latest conversation with its attachments?
I have used MS GraphAPI to get the mail conversations from my mail and to my email. But the conversations is coming full with previous all reply messages, I need the latest reply or new mail with its attachments how to achieve this. I have tried but still not getting the correct ? please let me know,  If anyone help with that.
        def extract_hr_elements(html_content):
            try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
                hr_elements = soup.find_all('hr', tabindex="-1", style="display:inline-block; width:98%")
                return len(hr_elements), hr_elements
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in extract_hr_elements: {e}")
                return 0, []

        def fetch_latest_email(folder):
            try:
                token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MICROSOFT_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
            
                data = {
                    'client_id': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
                    'client_secret': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    'grant_type': 'password',
                    'scope': MICROSOFT_SCOPES,
                    'username': MICROSOFT_USERNAME,
                    'password': MICROSOFT_PASSWORD,
                }
                
                response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
                
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
                else:
                    print("Failed to obtain access token", response.text)
                    return None
            
                # Get the latest email from the specified folder
                headers = {
                    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
                folder_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folder}/messages?$top=1&$orderby=receivedDateTime desc'
                folder_r = requests.get(folder_url, headers=headers)
                latest_email = folder_r.json().get('value')[0]
                
                return latest_email
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in fetch_latest_email: {e}")
                return None


        def fetch_latest_email_inbox_and_sent():
            try:
                latest_inbox_email = fetch_latest_email('inbox')
                latest_sent_email = fetch_latest_email('sentitems')

                if latest_inbox_email:
                    print("The latest email from the Inbox folder:")
                    print_email_details(latest_inbox_email)

                if latest_sent_email:
                    print("The latest email from the Sent Items folder:")
                    print_email_details(latest_sent_email)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in fetch_latest_email_inbox_and_sent: {e}")

        # Function to print email details including HTML content
        def print_email_details(email):
            try:
                print(f"Subject: {email.get('subject')}")
                print(f"From: {email.get('from').get('emailAddress').get('address')}")
                print(f"To: {', '.join([recipient.get('emailAddress').get('address') for recipient in email.get('toRecipients', [])])}")
                print(f"Received Date: {email.get('receivedDateTime')}")

                body_html = email.get('body', {}).get('content', 'No Body Content')
                hr_count, hr_elements = extract_hr_elements(body_html)
                
                print(f"Number of <hr> elements: {hr_count}")
                
                if hr_count > 0:
                    print("Details of <hr> elements:")
                    for idx, hr in enumerate(hr_elements):
                        print(f"HR Element {idx + 1}: {hr}")

                # Print the full body
                print("Full email body:")
                print(body_html)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error in print_email_details: {e}")


        fetch_latest_email_inbox_and_sent()

